# Query that removes specific duplicated rows from a datatable

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery, data-manipulation

I have an intervals datatable where everytime an event is triggered it gets a datestamp of the event with and start time, and when that event ends, it gets another row with the same id that includes the end time.

This is how my table looks like:

```
|   | datestamp | interval_uid | start_time | end_time |
|---|-----------|--------------|------------|----------|
| 1 | 10:37     | 1            | 10:37      | null     |
| 2 | 10:38     | 2            | 10:38      | null     |
| 3 | 10:41     | 1            | 10:37      | 10:41    |
```

I want to set a scheduled query that deletes the rows that **have another duplicated interval_uid** and **have no end_time**. This is how table1 should look after the query:

```
|   | datestamp | interval_uid | start_time | end_time |
|---|-----------|--------------|------------|----------|
| 1 | 10:38     | 2            | 10:38      | null     |
| 2 | 10:41     | 1            | 10:37      | 10:41    |
```

Currently I select the the unwanted rows with this query and save it into **table2**:

```
SELECT
  a.*
FROM
  `table1` a
JOIN (
  SELECT
    interval_uid,
    COUNT(*)
  FROM
    `table1`
  GROUP BY
    interval_uid
  HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1) b
ON
  a.interval_uid = b.interval_uid
WHERE
  duration IS NULL --or end_time IS NULL
```

I can visualize the table I would want to have with this query

```
SELECT *
FROM `table1`
EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT *
FROM `table_2`
```

Is it possible to have all these within a single query that I can schedule so everyday all unwanted rows get deleted from table1?

Answer (score 0):

How about using aggregation?

```
select datestamp, interval_uid, start_time, max(end_time) as end_time
from t
group by datestamp, interval_uid, start_time;
```

You can save this into a separate table directly.

EDIT:

To delete the rows:

```
delete from t
    where t.end_time is null and
          exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.datestamp = t.datestamp and
                        t2.interval_uid = t.interval_uid and
                        t2.start_time = t.start_time and
                        t2.end_time is not null
                 );
```

Comment: I need to delete the rows in the table, not create another table. Also I only showed 4 fields, but there are actually 14 where only interval_uid and start_time are coincident on duplicated rows.

Comment: @Abutreca . . . Your question is unclear about the `delete` because you only show `select` queries.

Comment: They are just examples to show what I want. I explained in the text that I want to delete rows from the table I have.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this instead of using a DELETE sentence, could be using the current queries you have and overwrite the existing table.

As you mention you are using 2 querys to get the data as you want, based on this, you scheduled query could be like:

```
WITH table1 as (
    SELECT
    a.*
    FROM
    table1 a
    JOIN (
    SELECT
        interval_uid,
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        table1
    GROUP BY
        interval_uid
    HAVING
        COUNT(*) > 1) b
    ON
    a.interval_uid = b.interval_uid
    WHERE
    duration IS NULL --or end_time IS NULL
)

SELECT *
FROM table1
EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT *
FROM table2
```

After this, when creating the scheduled query you can set the [configuration](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query) to [overwrite](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#destination_table) the table.

Keep in mind that DELETE is a DML statement and the current [limit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#data_manipulation_language_statements) is 1,000 operations per table.

Comment: thats a possibility, but isn't poorly optimized to overwrite a 100k+ rows table everyday instead of just deleting a few rows?

Comment: If you want to use the DELETE statement you also will need to query all the table to detect the duplicates by using aggregations, maybe this post can be helpful https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-deduplication-14a1206efdbb